# Identify config file format and possible python module to parse it

Tags: python, parsing, config

I am trying to parse the config file located here (http://pastebin.com/raw/49qZYkU4) but I am unsure what format it is.

Is this a standard format or will I need to write something to parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Lua source code. The comments starting with `--` look suspicious.

Comment: Thanks Roland. It is Lua indeed. I also found a module that will parse Lua data structures. [SLPP](https://github.com/SirAnthony/slpp)